# Iterative Parsing Non-XML?

Tags: python, python-2.7

so I'm looking to parse a string and flatten it which contains a variable depth of numbers.

Here is an example of the string:

```
'(7&(10&(22|25))|(22&25)|(25&(10|22)))|(9&(10&(22|25))|(22&25)|(25&(10|22)))|(33&22&25)'
```

What this means, is that we have 3 different possibilities in the first level, as represented by this list:

```
['7&(10&(22|25))|(22&25)|(25&(10|22))', '9&(10&(22|25))|(22&25)|(25&(10|22))', '33&22&25']
```

The last option in this list can only be one thing (as it has no interior levels).

However, the first is quite variable:, so I'll focus on that:
The '7&' means that every element in that level has a 7.

So then we extract the child levels from that, and we get:

```
['10&(22|25)', '22&25', '25&(10|22)']
```

So here, index 1 is a dead end, so our final output for that tree is '7&22&25'. For index 0, we have a parent of 7&10& and a child of 22|25, which means separate trees, so our final is 7&10&22 and 7&10&25, and for the last, we have 7&25&10 and 7&25&22.

Is there any way I could do this iteratively? I already have parsers to extract a single level and to extract if there is a numerical character plus an ampersand and extract the child levels.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want here is not iteration, but [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29).

Assuming your have a parser function "parse" that can take a string and return a list of children strings, it might look something like this:

```
def parse_recursively(string):
    if (string is dead end): # base case
        return [string]

    else:
        children = parse(string) # returns a list of children strings
        rv = list()
        for s in children:
            rv.extend(parse_recursively(s))

        return rv
```